# Why are SVG filter effects blurry in Firefox on Mac OS?

Tags: svg, svg-filters

It seems that SVG filter effects are rendered strangely in Firefox on Mac OS. I came across this issue when trying to implement a drop shadow for a shape with a 1px stroke. I did some pixel snapping in Javascript along with a 0.5px offset and this makes the 1px stroke render crisply as long as there is no drop shadow.

However, when I apply the drop shadow with a filter effect the shape is blurry, but only in Firefox on Mac OS (I've tried Firefox and Chrome on Mac OS and Linux).

Here's some sample code:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>

    <!-- A trivial filter that shouldn't really do anything, to demonstrate a minimal case -->
    <filter id="f1" x="-10%" y="-10%" width="120%" height="120%" filterRes="100">
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
      </feMerge>
    </filter>

    <!-- A more representative example where this issue is annoying: a drop shadow -->
    <filter id="f2" x="-10%" y="-10%" width="200%" height="200%" filterRes="100">
      <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="2" dy="2" />
      <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="offOut" stdDeviation="2" />
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode in="blurOut"/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
      </feMerge>
    </filter>

  </defs>

  <!-- Translating by 0.5 px so that 1px borders are sharp -->
  <g transform="translate(5.5,5.5)">
    <rect width="20" height="20" rx="2" ry="2" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="white" />
    <rect x="30" width="20" height="20" rx="2" ry="2" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="white" filter="url(#f1)" />
    <rect x="60" width="20" height="20" rx="2" ry="2" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="white" filter="url(#f2)" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

The svg looks fine in Firefox on Linux: (sorry I can't post inline images as a new SO user)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QdPr.png

and the same in Chrome on Mac OS (I can only post 2 links as a new SO user, so no link to the screenshot, but it's essentially identical), but the `rect`s with the filter effects applied are blurry in Firefox on Mac OS:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2KHw.png

I've tried several tweaks to no avail, including:

- Using `feBlend` or `feComposite` instead of `feMerge`
- Bumping up `filterRes` to browser-destroyingly high values

Any ideas?

(Apologies for not including a working demo -- I attempted to create a jsfiddle but it doesn't really work properly because the pixel snapping Javascript code doesn't work when the SVGs are in a frame the way jsfiddle does things.)

Comment: Here are some links I couldn't include in the original post: [the Javascript pixel snapping technique](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/issues/175) and [my attempt at a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Akzbt/2/).

Comment: You should file a bugreport: http://bugs.mozilla.org.

Comment: @ErikDahlström good suggestion. [Bug filed.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=772787)

Comment: I encountered this problem intermittently, depending on whether certain font and line-height values were set. I think it may be related to how Firefox does rounding (numerical, not of corners).